# Obter diretório do servidor

Tags: php, diretório

Como posso pegar o diretório onde se localiza o servidor usando PHP?

O diretório do servidor e não do arquivo onde sera executado o *script*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que é isto que você quer:

```
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ITie60). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lonnxxwp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/GetDirectory.php).

Documentação [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) e [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) e [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

O `__FILE__` dá o caminho do arquivo, o `dirname()` pega só o diretório ignorando o nome do arquivo (pode ser feito com qualquer *path* já que o que ele pega é o diretório pai do *path* passado) e o `realpath()` pega o caminho absoluto do endereço relativo encontrado. Dá para usar uma combinação deles de acordo com a necessidade.

Answer (score 5):

Essa informação pode ser obtida através da *array* [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) passando como argumento `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

> **DOCUMENT_ROOT**: O diretório raiz sob onde o script atual é executado,
>   como definido no arquivos de configuração do servidor.

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: +1 por fazer o que a pergunta pede

Comment: @GabrielHenrique estranho, pois o meu servidor (que é o que a pergunta pede) não fica na document root, apenas o conteúdo do site.

Comment: @Bacco Em certos casos como o seu o DocumentRoot pode não ter sido definido, além do modo apresentado pelo bigown, talvez isso também funcione nesses casos: `echo substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));`.

Comment: @Qmechanic73 eu sei o que é o DocumentRoot, o document root é a pasta dos documentos (tradução literal), que é onde ficam as páginas do site. Inclusive o meu sistema é modificado para o document root apontar pra pastas virtuais  dinamicamente. Sua resposta está ok, o que eu postei foi em relação ao que o Gabriel falou, como se sua resposta fosse a que faz o que foi perguntado. Mas o que foi perguntado não foi pasta do site, e sim "pasta do servidor". Esta aparece no PHPinfo, mas não é a da sua resposta e nem a do bigown.

Comment: Em outras palavras: creio que o autor não se expressou bem, por isto duas respostas boas que não respondem o que foi perguntado literalmente - porém respondem à possível necessidade real do autor (e se não for isso, o autor deve se manifestar em contrário ;) )